# JSON timestamp wrong on FIWARE Orion Context Broker global instance

Tags: fiware-orion

I am sending a POST request to http://orion.lab.fiware.org:1026/v2/entities/85/attrs?type=UrbansenseLocation in order to update *atime* and *bundle* attributes:

```
{
"atime":{
    "type":"Number",
    "value":1476370651},
"bundle":{
    "type":"Number",
    "value":1}
}
```

and a GET request to the same entity receives the following response:

```
{
"id": "85",
"type": "UrbansenseLocation",
"atime": {
    "type": "Number",
    "value": 1476370000,
    "metadata": {}
},
"bundle": {
    "type": "Number",
    "value": 1,
    "metadata": {}
},
//some other attributes
}
```

Please, note the mismatch on the value field of the *atime* attribute!!! Why is such thing happening?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems you have reported about this in the Orion repostitory at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2603. Let's continue at github, next come back to SOF when the solution to the problem gets clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that `atime` is meant to be a datetime. In that case, I'd suggest to use the `DateTime` attribute type. This would provide a better semantic for the attribute and should avoid any number rending problem (as the ones that [are being discussed right now at github](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2603)).

More information about the `DateTime` type at the [NGSIv2 specification](http://fiware.github.io/specifications/ngsiv2/stable/) (section "Special Attribute Types") and [this document](http://www.slideshare.net/fermingalan/ngsiv2-overview-for-developers-that-already-know-ngsiv1) (look for the "Datetime support" slide).